# GAE JPA 2.0 Txn rollback fast

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, transactions

One more time I am going nuts over something that never used to happen before. I have changed a few files in my project (In the presentation layer and the entities them selves, and have nothing to do with the data handling layer). Can someone please tell me why would the following code result in this error log? I mean why doesnt it see that I have commited the Txn and closed the EntityManager.
I have made the warning in bold because that is the problem, not the NullPointerException. The NullPointerException is a result that the query didnt return anything and teacher stayed null because the transaction rolled back and I have no clue why.

```
String Email = "xyz@xyz.com";
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
TypedQuery<Teacher> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Teacher s WHERE s.Email = ?1", Teacher.class);
query.setParameter(1, Email);
Teacher teacher = (Teacher)query.getSingleResult();
teacher.getTeacherInf(); // Lazy Parameter
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
//Lazy Parameter must be fetched before closing. Tried without fetching, same result
```

Here is the Teacher.class

```
@Entity
public class Teacher implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5426530769458891752L;
@Id
private long ID;
private String FName;
private String LName;
private String Email;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private TeacherInfo teacherInf;
// Constructor & getters & setters ...}
```

and finally here is the Error and Warning

**Sep 01, 2014 5:01:28 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter handleAbandonedTxns
WARNING: Request completed without committing or rolling back transaction with id 1.  Transaction will be rolled back.
Sep 01, 2014 5:01:28 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn**

**WARNING: /Login**

**java.lang.NullPointerException**
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.fetchLongField(QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.java:74)
    at org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityUtils.getApplicationIdentityForResultSetRow(IdentityUtils.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1011)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:229)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveAll(LazyResult.java:121)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.size(LazyResult.java:115)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.size(StreamingQueryResult.java:151)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.toArray(AbstractQueryResult.java:400)
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:559)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.JavaQueryEvaluator.execute(JavaQueryEvaluator.java:160)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.JPQLEvaluator.execute(JPQLEvaluator.java:112)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery.performExecute(JPQLQuery.java:200)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1789)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1693)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getSingleResult(JPAQuery.java:232)
    at servelet.User.Login.UserAuthentication.doPost(UserAuthentication.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at servelet.Filters.GlobalFilter.doFilter(GlobalFilter.java:27)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Updates:

I have made some testing and here is the results:
1) Primary Key look up ... no problem, works like a charm even through the Data Handling Layer.
2) TypedQueries give 2 kinds of error:
   A) if entity exists, I get NullPointerException (the Warning and Error posted above)
   B) if the entity doesnt exist, I get a ResultNotFoundException (Well thats pretty normal)

but the point here is that the Query find the Entity and only does that if it exists, and if there is no result, it gives ResultNotFoundException.

Please at this point I am willing to pretty much try anything and everything to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used a `long` (primitive) as my Id field, I had the exact same stack trace that you reported. All I had to do was change the type to `Long` (class).

Answer (score 0):

Well I still have no clue what was going on and would appreciate any added feed back, but it seems that as soon as I removed the Long ID and converted it to a Key (although another entity, same project has Long primary keys and all works just fine), the queries started coming through like a charm ... Anyway, I hope some one with much more experience could explain this behavior cause this one really got me